# how to dodge columns when using along with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to keep the columns separate in the following graph instead of stacked. I tried various places `position = "dodge"` in various places but to no avail. Any help?

```r
library(pacman)
#> Warning: package 'pacman' was built under R version 4.2.1
p_load(tidyverse)
titanic = read.csv("https://code.datasciencedojo.com/datasciencedojo/tutorials/raw/master/Datasets/titanic.csv")
titanic$survived_label = ifelse(titanic$Survived == 0, "Survived",
                                "Dead")

titanic = titanic %>% mutate(family_size = 1 + SibSp + Parch)

titanic %>% group_by(Sex, survived_label, Pclass) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(family_size)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sex, mean, fill = factor(Pclass), 
             group = factor(survived_label)), position = "dodge"
         ) + 
  geom_col() + facet_wrap(~ survived_label)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Sex', 'survived_label'. You can override
#> using the `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You have put position="dodge" in the wrong place: Try `geom_col(position = "dodge")`. Also even with that you will not get dodged bars because of `group = factor(survived_label)`. Hence: Remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a varied implementation of @stefan's suggestion:

```
library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)

titanic %>% group_by(Sex, survived_label, Pclass) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(family_size)) %>% 
  mutate(label_Pclass = paste0("Class ", Pclass)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sex, mean, fill = survived_label)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) + 
  facet_wrap(~ label_Pclass)+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE,
                     option = "E")+
  theme_ipsum_ps()+
  ggtitle("Survial Titanic dataset")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Survival"))
```

[image]